# Wix fetch call in backend gets 'time-out after 14 seconds' error

Tags: javascript, fetch, velo

When using a fetch request through backend code,  I get a  ["WebMethod request timed-out after 14 seconds... Did you forget to resolve a promise?"] . When I run the exact same code on front end, it makes the request perfectly fine and updates my third-party resource as expected with 1 second. What would cause the request to time out at 14 seconds and how should I go about fixing this?

I was using Wix's API documentation as well as this article for using fetch as backend code: https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-accessing-third-party-services-with-the-fetch-api

Backend code:

```
export function sendRequest() {
 let url = "https://www.some.com/url";

 return fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
 "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"token": "someToken", "secret": "someSecret", "programID": "someID", "body": "someAES"})
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response.status))
}
```

Frontend code:

```
import * as process from 'backend/newprocess';

export function exportPart(event) {
    console.log("Sending request")
    process.sendRequest()
    .then(result => {console.log("It worked bruh!")})
}
```

Running the backend code as frontend code, it runs perfectly fine and updates my external resource as expected in less than 1 second. I would expect the backend call would be similar times but instead, it time-outs and logs "["WebMethod request timed-out after 14 seconds... Did you forget to resolve a promise?"]" error. I have also tried adding .catch() after both .then() and the result is gives me the .catch() response instead after the 14 seconds.

Comment: Please refrain from putting "SOLVED" in the title, and other equivalent phrases.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by the realization of where the wix-fetch call was coming from. I was hitting a local server that I have running on a raspberry pi. Since it has a self-assigned certificate, by default, it is flagged by browsers and servers when trying to connect as being a security risk. 
The resolution was hitting my API on my AWS instance which deals and issues CA certificates and therefore was valid and fetch now resolves successfully from the back end.

Moral of the story: Backend fetch calls must be made to non self-assigned certificate endpoints otherwise it will time out.